# Grammar with issues - optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string

Tags: antlr4

I am in process of writing a new grammar file for [openHAB](https://www.openhab.org/) project configuration files. Existing implementation rely on Eclipse Xtext which is great for IDE tooling, but makes things pretty hard when it comes to embedding. Since Xtext is "stuck" with 10 years old Antlr3 version which makes its generated grammar fail with Antlr4, even after adjustments.

I've stubbed on several things, which I (hopefully) solved. However, there is an issue in grammar I've made which I can't solve myself. Due to my inexperience in area I see no alternative (better) way to write grammar.

Below grammar have several tough problems:

1. Conflict between various value types and ID, UID and UID_SEGMENTs - I've attempted to solve these through moving them to lexer rules, however it does not help much.
2. There are several optional parts which are repeated across `Thing` and `Bridge` definitions - namely label, bridgeUID, location and properties.

So far grammar fails to pass validation due to below:

> warning: 17:0: rule modelBridge contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
>
> warning: 17:0: rule modelBridge contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
>
> warning: 34:0: rule modelThing contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
>
> warning: 46:0: rule modelChannel contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string

I believe issue comes down to UID, cause manipulation on these parts moves things a bit forward, but still I can't parse reference file.
I am open for suggestions on how to adjust rules. I've read most of related answers within SO already, however they do not answer my issue, simply because this grammar is a little bit different.

```
grammar thingz;

things: (modelThing | modelBridge)* EOF;

modelBridge:
  BRIDGE (id=UID | thingTypeId=UID_SEGMENT thingId=UID_SEGMENT)
  (label=STRING)?
  (L_PAREN bridgeUID=UID R_PAREN)?
  (LOCATION location=STRING)?
  (properties=modelProperties)?
  (L_BRACE
    (
      THINGS?
      ( modelThing | modelBridge) *
    )?
    CHANNELS?
     modelChannel*
  R_BRACE)?
  ;


modelThing:
  THING (id=UID | thingTypeId=UID_SEGMENT thingId=UID_SEGMENT)
  (label=STRING)?
  (L_PAREN bridgeUID=UID R_PAREN)?
  (LOCATION location=STRING)?
  (properties=modelProperties)?
  (L_BRACE
    CHANNELS? modelChannel*
    R_BRACE
  )?
  ;

modelChannel:
  (channelDeclaration | channelReference)
  ':' id=CHANNEL_ID
    (label=STRING)?
  properties=modelProperties?
;

modelProperties:
(L_BRACKET
    properties=modelProperty? (',' properties=modelProperty)*
R_BRACKET)?
;

channelDeclaration: (channelKind=(STATE | TRIGGER))? type=modelItemType;
channelReference: TYPE channelType=STRING;

modelItemType :
  baseModelItemType | 'Number:' ID
;

baseModelItemType :
  'Switch' | 'Rollershutter' | 'Number' | 'String' | 'Dimmer' | 'Contact' | 'DateTime' | 'Color' | 'Player' | 'Location' | 'Call' | 'Image'
;

modelProperty:
  key=ID '=' value=valueType (',' value=valueType)*
;

valueType:
  STRING | NUMBER | BOOLEAN
;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';

//STRING: '"' ( 'a'..'z' 'A'..'Z' ) '"';

THING: 'Thing';
THINGS: 'Things:';
BRIDGE: 'Bridge';
CHANNELS: 'Channels:';
L_PAREN: '(';
R_PAREN: ')';
L_BRACE: '{';
R_BRACE: '}';
L_BRACKET: '[';
R_BRACKET: ']';
LOCATION: '@';
TYPE: 'Type';
STATE: 'State';
TRIGGER: 'Trigger';

MINUS: '-';
STRING  :
  '"'  ( '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|'\''|'\\') | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"' |
  '\'' ( '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|'\''|'\\') | ~('\\'|'\'') )* '\''
;

CHANNEL_ID:
    UID_SEGMENT ('#' UID_SEGMENT)?
;

UID:
  UID_SEGMENT ':' UID_SEGMENT ':' UID_SEGMENT ( ':' UID_SEGMENT )*
;

UID_SEGMENT :
  ID
;

ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')+;

INTEGER: MINUS? DIGIT;
DECIMAL: MINUS? DIGIT? '.' DIGIT+;
NUMBER: DECIMAL | INTEGER;
DIGIT: '0'..'9';

WS
   : ( ' ' | [ \t\r\n]+ ) -> channel ( HIDDEN )
   ;
```

I would expect the test file to parse correctly:

```
Bridge mqtt:broker:MyMQTTBroker [ host="192.168.178.50", secure=false, username="MyUserName", password="MyPassword"] {
  Thing topic sonoff_Dual_Thing "Light_Dual" @ "Sonoff" {
    Channels:
      Type switch : PowerSwitch1  [ stateTopic="stat/sonoff_dual/POWER1" , commandTopic="cmnd/sonoff_dual/POWER1", on="ON", off="OFF"]
      Type switch : PowerSwitch2  [ stateTopic="stat/sonoff_dual/POWER2" , commandTopic="cmnd/sonoff_dual/POWER2", on="ON", off="OFF"]
      Type string : Version [stateTopic="stat/sonoff_dual/STATUS2", transformationPattern="JSONPATH:$.StatusFWR.Version"]
      }
  Thing topic sonoff_TH_Thing "Light_TH" @ "Sonoff" {
    Channels:
      Type switch : PowerSwitch  [ stateTopic="stat/sonoff_TH/POWER", commandTopic="cmnd/sonoff_TH/POWER", on="ON", off="OFF" ]
      Type string : Version [stateTopic="stat/sonoff_TH/STATUS2", transformationPattern="JSONPATH:$.StatusFWR.Version"]
      Type number : Temperature [stateTopic="tele/sonoff_TH/SENSOR", transformationPattern="JSONPATH:$.AM2301.Temperature"]
      Type number : Humidity [stateTopic="tele/sonoff_TH/SENSOR", transformationPattern="JSONPATH:$.AM2301.Humidity"]
   }
}
```

This file is an example from [official documentation](https://www.openhab.org/docs/configuration/things.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of `modelBridge` is not correct:

```
(properties=modelProperties)?
```

because `modelProperties` already matches an empty string:

```
modelProperties:
(L_BRACKET
    properties=modelProperty? (',' properties=modelProperty)*
R_BRACKET)?
;
```

Simply remove the `?` at the end:

```
modelProperties
 : L_BRACKET properties=modelProperty? (',' properties=modelProperty)* R_BRACKET
 ;
```

And this part is also not correct:

```
(
  THINGS?
  ( modelThing | modelBridge) *
)?
```

Given that the part `THINGS? (modelThing | modelBridge)*` also already matches an empty string, it doesn'n make sense to make it optional. Here too, remove the `?`:

```
(
  THINGS?
  ( modelThing | modelBridge) *
)
```

That will fix the warnings at least.

#### EDIT

And you have the following overlapping lexer tokens:

```
CHANNEL_ID:
    UID_SEGMENT ('#' UID_SEGMENT)?
;

UID_SEGMENT :
  ID
;
```

Both `CHANNEL_ID` and `UID_SEGMENT` match what an `ID` also matches. This causes the lexer to never create `ID` tokens (because `ID` is placed after these 2 lexer rules). Write these 2 lexer rules as parser rules and use `channel_id` and `uid_segment` in your other parser rules:

```
channel_id
 : ID ('#' ID)?
 ;

uid_segment
 : ID
 ;
```

Finally, you had `channelReference : TYPE channelType=STRING;` while your input has `Type switch : ...`. Change that into `channelReference : TYPE channelType=ID;`.

When doing so, you'll end up with the following grammar:

```
grammar thingz;

things: (modelThing | modelBridge)* EOF;

modelBridge
 : BRIDGE (id=UID | thingTypeId=uid_segment thingId=uid_segment)
   (label=STRING)?
   (L_PAREN bridgeUID=UID R_PAREN)?
   (LOCATION location=STRING)?
   (properties=modelProperties)?
   (L_BRACE THINGS? (modelThing | modelBridge)* CHANNELS? modelChannel* R_BRACE)?
 ;


modelThing
 : THING (id=UID | thingTypeId=uid_segment thingId=uid_segment)
   (label=STRING)?
   (L_PAREN bridgeUID=UID R_PAREN)?
   (LOCATION location=STRING)?
   (properties=modelProperties)?
   (L_BRACE CHANNELS? modelChannel* R_BRACE)?
 ;

modelChannel
 : (channelDeclaration | channelReference) ':' id=channel_id (label=STRING)? properties=modelProperties?
 ;

modelProperties
 : L_BRACKET properties=modelProperty? (',' properties=modelProperty)* R_BRACKET
 ;

channelDeclaration
 : (channelKind=(STATE | TRIGGER))? type=modelItemType
 ;

channelReference
 : TYPE channelType=ID
 ;

modelItemType
 : baseModelItemType
 | 'Number:' ID
 ;

baseModelItemType
 : 'Switch'
 | 'Rollershutter'
 | 'Number'
 | 'String'
 | 'Dimmer'
 | 'Contact'
 | 'DateTime'
 | 'Color'
 | 'Player'
 | 'Location'
 | 'Call'
 | 'Image'
 ;

modelProperty
 : key=ID '=' value=valueType (',' value=valueType)*
 ;

valueType
 : STRING
 | number
 | BOOLEAN
 ;

channel_id
 : ID ('#' ID)?
 ;

uid_segment
 : ID
 ;

number
 : DECIMAL
 | INTEGER
 ;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
THING: 'Thing';
THINGS: 'Things:';
BRIDGE: 'Bridge';
CHANNELS: 'Channels:';
L_PAREN: '(';
R_PAREN: ')';
L_BRACE: '{';
R_BRACE: '}';
L_BRACKET: '[';
R_BRACKET: ']';
LOCATION: '@';
TYPE: 'Type';
STATE: 'State';
TRIGGER: 'Trigger';

MINUS: '-';
STRING
 : '"'  ( '\\' [btnfru"'\\] | ~[\\"] )* '"'
 | '\'' ( '\\' [btnfru"'\\] | ~[\\'] )* '\''
 ;

UID
 : ID ':' ID ':' ID ( ':' ID )*
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

INTEGER
 : MINUS? DIGIT+
 ;

DECIMAL
 : MINUS? DIGIT? '.' DIGIT+
 ;

WS
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;

fragment DIGIT
 : [0-9]
 ;
```

which parses your example input correctly.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, these are indeed fixes which make grammar work! I made it a try and I was able to parse whole reference file with just minor parser issues.

Comment: Good to hear that @splatch. Checkout my suggested grammar which also uses some v4 notation where you used v3 notation (both work). I also promoted `NUMBER` to a parser rule since that would never be matched because both `INTEGER` and `DECIMAL` were defined before it.

Comment: I've been polishing it further over past two hours and got it close to yours. Once I got your fixes in, things began to align. By debugging stuff in antlr-lab I've spotted bug with channelType (took me a moment to realize why reference file didn't fly), then I got into uid vs channel id. Finally I've adjusted number handling to be
`INTEGER: MINUS? DIGIT+;` and `DECIMAL: MINUS? DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+;` as they did not match properly.